# Why does Marle say "Must be my imagination"?

Tags: video-games, final-fantasy

I'm trying to understand why Marle says "Must be my imagination"

> *Upon approaching Marle.*
> **Tifa**: Hey, Marle. We took care of the filters, so we're gonna head back to the bar now.
>
> **Marle**: Take care you two! ...Oh? You're looking pretty chipper!
>
> **Tifa**: Uh...I don't feel that different.
>
> **Marle**: Must be my imagination then. Anyway! Keep your wits about you, merc! A token of my appreciation. Be good to her.

- [Script Reference](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_VII_Remake_script)

Why does Marle say *Must be my imagination*? Was she imagining Tifa was  pretty chipper?

Comment: Note to close voters: These types of questions [are not off topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11626/58193).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Must be my imagination" is a phrase that technically indicates that a person is saying that they must have been wrong, that they only imagined that something was the case. However, in common usage, it is often used as a more begrudging agreement, indicating that the speaker isn't actually convinced it was not the case, but that they're ceding the point. In normal social interaction, this is inferred by voice inflection and facial expression. Here, we pretty much just have to accept that this statement could be made sincerely or sarcastically.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, FuzzyBoots' [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/254202/106383) is correct. In this specific case, I have to disagree. Marle knows Tifa well enough to tell that she is in a better mood (because Cloud is there). Tifa either doesn't want to admit it, or isn't even aware of her own mood improvement. Marle doesn't want to embarass her, so she discounts it even though she knows she didn't imagine it.

Marle indicated earlier in the story that Tifa has feelings for Cloud (more than just friendship):

> **Marle**: If you ever need an ear to bend, I'll lend you mine. Can be
> about anything—even Tifa.
>
> **Cloud**: What's she to you?
>
> **Marle**: The granddaughter I never had. And if you hurt her, I'll take
> it out of your hide. You hear me?

and

> **Cloud**: ...We're already friends.
>
> **Marle**: So when she talks, are you really listening? Thinking about her
> and her feelings? Or are you just going through the motions?

Comment: “Uh...I don't feel that different” she doesn’t want to admit it,could you explain a little more?

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley I'm not sure how else to explain it. Have you played the game? Tifa may be embarassed to admit her feelings for Cloud in front of him, although if I have to guess I would say that at this point she hasn't even admitted to herself how she really feels.